# Setting a cookie on a domain and picking it up on a sub-domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have set a cookie (in Javascript) at: `www.sampledomain.com` but when I go to `blurrrp.sampledomain.com` I can't seem to see it :(

My cookie domain is set to `"/"` but that isn't right :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the cookie for the domain: example.com

Answer (score 1):

That's because `x.example.com` is not a subdomain of `www.example.com`.

You need to get rid of the `www`, or change the subdomain to `x.www.example.com`.